# I'm booted into an Debian image supposedly Debian 8 but on the desktop and in applications it says:"install Debian Sid" everywhere

Tags: debian, system-installation, live-usb

I've downloaded Debian Jessie(8) from the official site, here is the filename:

```
debian-live-8.0.0-amd64-lxde-desktop
```

And I'm currently booted into it on another computer through usb, but it say's **Install Debian Sid** on the desktop and in applications.

**What is going on here?** Am I just going crazy or is Debian Sid=Unstable and not version 8, I also checked the checksum and that was all normal.

Here is a quote from debians site:

> The current "stable" distribution of Debian is version **8**,
>   codenamed **jessie**.

and right above the link to the download it say's:

> Official live install images for the "stable" release

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a bug in [`debian-installer-launcher`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/debian-installer-launcher); it stores the wrong values for the distribution name and version. The live CD does contain Jessie, and that's what will be installed (even though the icon and menu entry say "Install Debian sid").

You can verify this by checking the following in a terminal started from the live CD:

```
cat /etc/debian_version
lsb_release -ic
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: What would you consider confirmation of the bug? If you know how Debian packages are built you can see the problem in the package's [source code](https://sources.debian.net/src/debian-installer-launcher/19/debian/rules/). I've filed the bug as [#787131](https://bugs.debian.org/787131), you can subscribe to it to see what the maintainer thinks of it...

Comment: I've filed bugs just not for Debian and couldn't find one. You didn't mention if you reproduced the behaviour your self or if you've seen it somwhere. The verification in your answer is helpful I'm just not near the system to try it. It also said Debian 8 in the installer when I went ahead with the install(in the upper right corner).

Comment: You can believe the actual installer ;-). I reproduced the bug myself, I thought it was weird enough to warrant investigating...